# How to edit wave audio files using C#?

Tags: c#, audio, edit, wav

I would like to make a program that can process audio.
How get an array of frames, while each frame has an array of tones with their volumes? (this is how audio is constructed.)

Basically its just an API to parse `WAV` files, and export `WAV` files.

Maybe there's a different way of editing audio?

Comment: You can use [this](https://naudio.codeplex.com/) library.

Comment: This codeproject article (http://www.codeproject.com/KB/audio-video/CSharpWAVClassAndMixing.aspx) titled "C# WAV file class, audio mixing, and some light audio manipulation" may be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wav (RIFF) files have nothing directly to do with tonal information (e.g. you could have a wav file of atonal noise), they instead contain a sampled waveform (per channel).

You could use some DSP processing techniques (such as various types of FFT processing, windowed, overlapped, etc.) to get different kinds of spectral information, or do something like granular analysis/resynthesis.